# Creating Users in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis

I am having trouble getting my head around setting up users in PostgreSQL (with PostGIS extension) - well in all honesty I've been banging my head against a wall on this for the past week.  I am currently working with a dataset which most users should only have read permissions and a small group should be able to edit/delete/insert.

I am following this article:-
http://osqa.sjsoft.com/questions/155/how-do-i-create-a-read-only-postgresql-account, and have followed a couple of other examples (basically the same content) found on the web

but each time I try to load my data in to QGIS I am getting messages like:-

Message1

```
Erroneous query: SELECT * FROM <schema>.<table> LIMIT 1 returns 7 [error: permissions denied for schema <schema>.  Line 1: SELECT * FROM <schema>.<table> LIMIT 1
]
```

Message2

```
Unable to access the <schema>.<table> relation.
The error message fromt he database was:
ERROR: permission denied for schema <schema>
Line 1: Select * from <schema>.<Tbale> LIMIT 1
SQL: SELECT * from <schema>.<table> LIMIT 1
```

I am using PGADMIN III on a PostGreSQL 9.2 database.  I'm pretty sure I have either missed a step or done something during Proof of Concept which is hindering me being able to set up accounts (would something like having trust set up for all access methods play a part in the issue I am getting?).

Comment: Looks like your problem isn't user accounts as such, but that you haven't `GRANT`ed appropriate rights to those user accounts so they can access the schema and table(s). See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html

Comment: Thanks @CraigRinger it seems I had missed a step.  To confirm i did the following: 1.) Create new Group Role, 2.) In the database tree, allow group to connect to the database in question, 3.) Within schemas, add the group with US permissions, 4.) within the schema rightclick the tables heading and use Grants Wizard to assign relevant priveleges, 5.) create a new login profile and assign as a member of the group.  I have tested with 2 groups one for read only and the other for editing and all appearing OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you created the user successfully, but forgot to [`GRANT` them rights to the schema and/or the tables within it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html).

If the user didn't exist, you wouldn't be able to log in at all.